# Finding indices of array where values meet condition. Python, numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

Can you help me simplify the following expression in a more concise pythonic form and possibly with numpy? The numpy.argwhere() built in did not work as expected when assessing if the value is between a low and high number.

```
myList = [4.2, 6.0, 10.2]
low = 10
high = 11

indicies = []
for i, v in enumerate(myList):
    if low < v < high:
        indicies.append(i)
```

In the following with np.argwhere:

```
import numpy as np

myList = np.array([4.2, 6.0, 10.2])
low = 10
high = 11


indiciesWorking = np.argwhere(low < myList)  # working


indiciesError = np.argwhere(low < myList < high)  # ValueError
```

this returns

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Add an example of `theta` and explain what was wrong with `numpy.argwhere()`, what you did and expected and actual results.

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing, I hope it's more clear now, I expected that I either get a value error at 'indiciesWorking' and at 'indiciesError' or at none of both. Also I'm not sure how to solve this simple problem in a concise numpy expression.

Comment: `np.argwhere` (and `np.where/nonzero`) is a Python function.  It's argument is evaluated before the function is called.  All `argwhere` looks for is "True" values in the argument array, and may return an "empty" result.  Your error is produced when evaluating the condition array, the `a<x<b`.  That form is valid for Python scalars, but as the error shows, not for numpy arrays.

Answer (score 5):

You need to split `low < myList < high` to two conditions

```
theta = np.array([10.2, 6.0, 10.2])
indices = np.argwhere((theta > low) & (theta < high))
```

This will give you an `ndarray` `[[0] [2]]` that you can change to 1d array using `[:,0]`, or simply use `where` instead

```
indices = np.where((theta > low) & (theta < high))[0]
print(indices) # [0 2]
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for that, I tried it like this, too, only with 'and' instead of '&' between the two conditions. Your code works for me.